# Getting MySQL fields in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I know this is possibly a duplicate but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM software', function(err, rows) {
  if (err) {
      next(new Error(err));
  } else {
      data.db = rows[1].language;
      data.no = rows.length;
      console.log(data.db);
  }
});
```

I am trying to reference a specific field in a row retrieved. I have a row called 'Language' in my table so have researched around and found that I can reference the name of the field. When I do this, it throws back `undefined` in the console. It returns the same when I reference any other field (i.e. id)

Comment: Might be the case,try exactly as in your db `rows[1].Language;`

Comment: Yes, this works!! Didn't realise it was case-sensitive. Thank you